# Admirable vs commendable

Tags: word-choice

I was wondering if someone lets me know which one of the following words sounds more idiomatic in my self-made example bellow:

> - Although he didn't win the game, but his effort was really.........

**A)** [admirable](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/admirable)

**B)** [commendable](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/commendable)

Based on dictionary definitions, these two words have lots of overlaps and are very similar. I do not have any idea which one is the correct choice in this specific example? Please help me to find the best choice and tell me why?

I am asking this question to be able to differentiate them from one another.

Comment: In the context of the effort given in a game, I'd opt for **commendable**.  It means "praiseworthy", whereas "admirable" means "worthy of emulation".

Comment: Does it sound incorrect if I use "admirable" or it is a matter of style?

Comment: Admirable is less commendable.

Comment: If you wanted to stress some virtue, for example, he did not give up but continued to give his all, then **admirable** would be good. But if you're describing his play as skill, then "commendable" would be better.

Comment: Thank you very much TRomano. Could you please make your comments an answer? :)

Comment: OK, last comment from me. Because I've been accused of being argumentative. How can anyone vote to close this question as being "off topic" because the OP didn't look it up in a dictionary? A dictionary doesn't tell you which collocation is more common, it will mention whether a word is archaic, obsolete, slang, or very formal, but not how often two words are used. The OP also showed research because the two links direct to their dictionary definitions!

Comment: @A-friend In contemporary American English (and probably British English), we native speakers won't usually use both *although* and *but* in the sentence you ask about. In such a sentence we  would use either *although* or *but*, not both. Using both words in such a sentence is old-fashioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both examples sound fine to me, but it's more common to use *admirable* or *commendable* **before** the noun *effort*.

The blue line plots the number of instances recorded in the American English corpus, the red line represents the number of British English occurrences.

**admirable effort**
[image]

**commendable effort**
[image]

The following chart demonstrates that in **American English**, the difference between *admirable effort* and *commendable effort* has decreased since the 1970s.

[image]

Comparing admirable/commendable effort with **effort was admirable** (green) and **effort was commendable** (yellow), the American English corpus produces the following results on [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=admirable%20effort%2Ccommendable%20effort%2Ceffort%20was%20admirable%2Ceffort%20was%20commendable&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadmirable%20effort%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccommendable%20effort%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceffort%20was%20admirable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceffort%20was%20commendable%3B%2Cc0).

The difference between the [**attributive**](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/attribadjterm.htm) and [**predicative**](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/predadjterm.htm) usage is dramatic.

[image]

The OP asked for an example, so from Google Books I found this

> Despite **an admirable effort** against the mighty New England Patriots the next week, Flynn wasn't able to lead the Packers to a win in Foxborough either.
>   <sub>*Green Bay Packers: The Complete Illustrated History - Third Edition*</sub>

Comment: What is your suggestion if I want to use admirable or commendable before the noun effort? Please provide me with a sentence. :)

Comment: @A-friend  Well, you could say: "He made an admirable effort.. OR ... a commendable effort despite losing the game." Your examples are not wrong, I think they're fine. But you asked about idiomaticity, the data suggests that the adjectives: admirable, and commendable  "before" *effort* is more commonly used.

Comment: I don't know why this answer got downvoted, an explanation would be nice (this answer is not useful?). But I've grown used to anonymous downvoting. How are we supposed to help learners if we do not explain? I couldn't give a rat's a*** about rep, but helping learners is something I do care about.

Comment: Overall, [***admirable*** is way more common than ***commendable***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=admirable%2Ccommendable&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadmirable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccommendable%3B%2Cc0), but [***a commendable effort*** is more common than ***an admirable effort***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+admirable+effort%2Ca+commendable+effort&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20admirable%20effort%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20commendable%20effort%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @FumbleFingers did you see the American English Ngram chart I posted? The one that shows nowadays the difference between the two is practically nil?

Comment: @FumbleFingers https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+admirable+effort%2Ca+commendable+effort&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20admirable%20effort%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20commendable%20effort%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Drilling down into the results of *my* chart for ***an admirable  / a commendable effort*** shows only a couple of dozen instances for each over the past few decades, but the fact that even today ***admirable*** is 4 times more common than ***commendable*** (a century ago it was **10** times more common) surely reflects the fact that in this *specific* context, speakers tend to buck the usual trend. But there's a pretty big *semantic* distinction anyway (and *I commend you* is ***much*** more "haughty" than *I admire you*, obviously).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Examples taken from **daily use** shows [**commendable effort**](http://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?q=commendable+effort&l=0&t=0&ffo=false&findid=-1&ff=) 25 results vs. [**admirable effort**](http://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?q=admirable+effort&l=0&t=0&ffo=false&findid=-1&ff=) 33 results. It appears that over time the difference between the two has narrowed down. The results are interesting, and appear to confirm  the  trend  has shifted, as the AmEng Ngram suggested.  Older speakers may prefer to use *commendable effort*, but can we say the same is true for younger native speakers today?

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I kinda doubt the *average* younger native speaker would be likely to use either. They're both somewhat dated/formal usages anyway, but it's also worth noting that ***effort*** in this context strongly implies ***unsuccessful** effort* (made by a competitor who *didn't win*, for example). And there's something a little odd about "admiring, commending" someone's efforts when you're not going to award them the formal recognition of a medal or certificate. Repeat your FRAZE·IT search (neat, that! :) with ***valiant effort*** and you'll get far more hits.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In the light of our discussion, I believe the question should be reopened. It appears that it's not such an open and shut case after all. And I'll say no more.

Comment: Note that there's a bit of a "register clash" here too - OP's ***really = very*** is rather colloquial, so it doesn't sit too well with dated/formal words like *admirable / commendable*. But at the end of the day I don't really think it's very useful to cite occurrence counts and try to decide which adjective to use on the basis of which is most common. Especially given Google Books doesn't have a single instance of *his effort was really **commendable** OR **admirable***. You may as well choose on the basis of semantics - do we *admire* him (ourselves), or *commend* him (to others)?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the two words do have considerable overlap, and are often used indiscriminately. There is no "wrong" choice here, simply a better one, depending on the idea you're trying to convey.

You give the example of a player's effort during a game.

If you wanted to stress some virtue of character, such as the player's continuing to give his best effort even when being outplayed by the opponent, then **admirable** would be a good choice, and **commendable** would also work. Virtues are worthy of emulation.

But if you wanted to stress the player's athletic skill and execution, such as not committing unforced errors, or making crisp accurate passes, then **admirable** wouldn't be as good a choice as **commendable**. Skills and execution are praiseworthy.  You can admire the player who has worked long and hard to perfect skills;  execution using those skills deserves praise.